# Two points fall on the segment [0; 1], and begin to move towards each other. Find the expected value of the coordinates of the meeting place.

Tags: probability

Two points fall on the segment [0; 1], and begin to move towards each other, and the left one moves at a speed three times less than the right one. Find the expected value of the coordinates of the meeting place.

Let x and y be the coordinates of the left and right points, respectively. Let 3u be the speed of the right point, then u is the speed of the left. The distance between the points is y-x, and the approach speed is 4u. Then the time until the meeting is (y-x) / 4u. Then the t coordinate of the meeting place is x + (y-x) u / 4u = 3x / 4 + y / 4. Then Et = 1 / 4E (x) + 3/4 * E (y). How to find E(x), E(y)?

Answer (score 1):

Let $U$ be the first point and $V$ be the second one. Then $ X = \min(U,V)$ and $Y = \max(U,V)$.

$$\mathbb E[X] = \mathbb E[\min(U,V)] = \iint_{[0,1]^2}\min(u,v)dudv = 2\int_0^1\int_0^uvdvdu = \int_0^1u^2du = \frac13$$
and $$\mathbb E[Y] = \mathbb E[U+V-X] = \frac12+\frac12-\frac13=\frac23.$$

Comment: Thank you so much!